# Unable to create endpoint with JDBC mssql in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to create endpoint in jsp, i have been able to connect to the database using the following code but i need to understand the structure of it.

```
<%
    String refNumb = request.getParameter("refNumb");    
       // String display = request.getParameter("display");
        //String msg = request.getParameter("message");
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://IPAddress;databaseName=FIRS",
            "user", "pass");

%>
```

Comment: What "structure"? It's just 3 statements. What is it you don't understand, and how were you able to write the code if you don't understand it?

Comment: How can I create a method/class that fetches from the database and displays the data in JSON when the method is called. Example MainClass.getListOfEmployees();

Comment: Your question is too broad. You're basically asking us to write all your code for you. Are you asking how to write a SQL query? How to use JDBC to run the query? How you iterate through the result of that query? How to give the result to the JSP? How for format the data as JSON? How to include that JSON in the JSP output? Or what? --- Pretty much all of those questions can be answered by searching the web, but that would require you to do you own **research**. Which you should always do before asking here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have successfully done the first step which is to connect to your database via jdbc. You can follow these steps after you successful fetched records from the database.

1. Convert your records into json string in java, you can use json library and follow the steps on how to convert your records to json
2. Create a jsp file and use out.print to print the records on your browser.
3. If you can get to step two then final step is to give a use the url of your jsp which is the end point. As long as anyone can display the json data from your db then that data can easily be consume via js or any other programming language.

You can also research via google on how to implement and consume webservices in java(Soap or rest) and follow the tutorial step by step.

Comment: *"I believe you are fetching records already"* Why do you believe that? There is certainly no evidence of it in the question.

Comment: I have been able to understand the structure. I will try to implement it and get back to you.  Thanks